# Stopped inheritance in a custom list. What persmissions needed at site level?

Tags: custom, custom-permission-level

I have created a custom list and have stopped inheritance in that. I am adding a user to this list and giving him a custom permission. He has Edit rights but not Manage list. Idea is to have this person initiate a SharePoint 2013 workflow (uses App step).

Once I have given him permission manually on the list do I also need to give him permission at the site level? What happens if I don't?

Answer (score 2):

I have replicated your scenario in local environment.

if you want to have access of only Custom List then whatever permission you have given on List that will hold good and user will be able to Edit the List but he will not able to access other pages of the Site until you provide at least  read only permission to the whole site. if you dont provide Site access user will be not able to access other Pages or even Site Contents will be forbidden.

click [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) for MS information of page for Unique Permission.